# Keep the number of running thread

Tags: c++builder, tthread

in my main application C++ builder, I create thread (Object TThread) to process file when i have a file in the list.
At same times, I need to keep the number of running thread.

i don't see how to do that? Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: Any idea?! At same time.. just I need to run x number thread until finish..

Answer (score 0):

You know when you are creating a new instance of your thread class.  Simply keep a counter of how many instances you create.  When each thread finishes, you can use its `OnTerminate` event to decrement your counter.